# Using LINQ to aggregate and group a list of data into a new list but Sum is 0

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of data retrieved from SQL and stored in a class. I want to now aggregate the data using LINQ in C# rather than querying the database again on a different dataset.

[image]

Example data I have is above.
Date, Period, Price, Vol and I am trying to create a histogram using this data. I tried to use Linq code below but seem to be getting a 0 sum.

1. Period needs to be a where clause based on a variable
2. Volume needs to be aggregated for the price ranges
3. Price needs to be a bucket and grouped on this column

I dont want a range. Just a number for each bucket.

Example output I want is (not real data just as example):

```
Bucket    SumVol
18000       50
18100       30
18200       20
```

Attempted the following LINQ query but my SUM seems to be be empty. I still need to add my where clause in, but for some reason the data is not aggregating.

```
var ranges = new[] { 10000, 11000, 12000, 13000, 14000, 15000, 16000, 17000, 18000, 19000, 20000 };
var priceGroups = eod.GroupBy(x => ranges.FirstOrDefault(r => r > x.price))
    .Select(g => new { Price = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(s => s.vol)})
    .ToList();

var grouped = ranges.Select(r => new
{
    Price = r,
    Sum = priceGroups.Where(g => g.Price > r || g.Price == 0).Sum(g => g.Sum)
});
```

Comment: What about reading [`GroupBy` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first... There seems to be nothing wrong with your **priceGroups** list. I've run that on my end and, as far as I can understand your purpose, it seems to be grabbing the expected values from your dataset.

```
var ranges = new[] { 10000, 11000, 12000, 13000, 14000, 15000, 16000, 17000, 18000, 19000, 20000 };
var priceGroups = eod.GroupBy(x => ranges.FirstOrDefault(r => r > x.price))
      .Select(g => new { Price = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(s => s.vol) })
      .ToList();
```

Now, I assume your intent with the **grouped** list was to obtain yet another anonymous type list, much like you did with your **priceGroups** list, which is also an anonymous type list... List<'a> in C#.

```
var grouped = ranges.Select(r => new
{
    Price = r,
    Sum = priceGroups.Where(g => g.Price > r || g.Price == 0).Sum(g => g.Sum)
});
```

For starters, your are missing the *ToList()* method call at the end of it. However, that's not the main issue here, as you could still work with an IEnumerable<'a> just as well for most purposes.

As I see it, the core problem is at your anonymous property **Sum** attribution. Why are your filtering for `g.Price > r || g.Price == 0`?

There is no element with **Price** equal to zero on your **priceGroups** list. Those are a subset of **ranges**, and there is no zero there. Then you are comparing every value in **ranges** against that subset in **priceGroups**, and consolidating the **Sums** of every element in **priceGroups** that have **Price** higher than the **range** being evaluated. In other words, the property **Sum** in your **grouped** list is a sum of sums.

Keep in mind that **priceGroups** is already an aggregated list. It seems to me you are trying to aggregate it again when you call the *Sum()* method after a *Where()* clause like you are doing. That doesn't make much sense.

What you want (I believe) for the **Sum** property in the **grouped** list is for it to be the same as the **Sum** property in the **priceGroups** list, if the **range** being evaluated matches the **Price** being evaluated. Furthermore, where there is no matches, you want your **grouped** list **Sum** to be zero, as that means the **range** being evaluated was not in the original dataset. You can achieve that with the following instead:

```
Sum = priceGroups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Price == r)?.Sum ?? 0
```

You said your **Sum** was "empty" in your post, but that's not the behavior I saw on my end. Try the above and, if still not behaving as you would expect, share a small dataset for which you know the expected output with me and I can try to help you further.

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ instead  to query the DB is great, mainly because you are saving process avoiding a new call to your DB. And in case you don't have a high update BD (that change the data  very quickly) you can use the retrived data to calculate all using LINQ